# Incompatible input in Keras Layer LSTM

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, keras-layer

I'm trying to replicate the [example on Keras's website](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/):

```
# as the first layer in a Sequential model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(10, 64)))
# now model.output_shape == (None, 32)
# note: `None` is the batch dimension.

# for subsequent layers, no need to specify the input size:
model.add(LSTM(16))
```

But when I run the following:

```
# only lines I've added: 
from keras.models import Sequential    
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM  

# all else is the same: 
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(10, 64)))
model.add(LSTM(16))
```

However, I get the following:
`ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_4: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2`

Versions:

```
Keras:      '2.0.5'  
Python:     '3.4.3'  
Tensorflow: '1.2.1'
```

Comment: Has my answer helped you?

Answer (score 2):

`LSTM` layer as their default option has to return only the last output from a sequence. That's why your data loses its sequential nature. In order to change that try:

```
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(10, 64), return_sequences=True))
```

What makes `LSTM` to return a whole sequence of predictions.